# foreach loop function result into array

Tags: php, arrays, binary-tree, hierarchical-data

i have this function:

```
 function subtree($id, $parents) { 
 echo $id;
 if (isset($parents[$id]))
 foreach ($parents[$id] as $child) 
{
 subtree($child, $parents);
}
}
```

the $parents is an array of each parent and his ( left , right childs )
the $id is the parent id i want the childs of.

```
$res = $db->query('SELECT p.id AS parent, GROUP_CONCAT( c.id ) AS children
 FROM rev_r_clients AS p
 JOIN rev_r_clients AS c ON c.parent_client_id = p.id
 GROUP BY p.id');

 $parents = Array();
 while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
 $parents[$row['parent']] = explode(',',$row['children']);
}
```

that the result of the loop function subtree is all in one page and not sorted. 
so what i want now is to get the childs result into a new array so i can sort or paginate it.

so any help modifying my code to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in your query, so all your parents and their children are already sorted before you even insert them into the array

```
SELECT p.id AS parent, c.id AS children
FROM rev_r_clients AS p
JOIN rev_r_clients AS c ON c.parent_client_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY p.id ASC, c.id ASC
```

(The way your joining tells me you have parents and children in one table, it just seems weird/wrong)

so an example output would be: (im assumming each parent only has a right or left child, but this works for any amount of children)

```
parent   children
1        1 
1        2
2        1
2        2
3        1
3        2
4        1
4        2
```

so its sorted by parents (lowest id -> greatest id), then their loweest id child -> highest id child

so when it goes into your loop

```
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
  $parents[$row['parent']][] = $row['children']
  $children[] = $row['children'];
}
```

it is automatically sorted.

$children array should contain ALL children in order of their parents then themselves.

$parents example output:

```
array(
  1 => array(1,2), 
  2 => array(1,2), 
  3 => array(1,2),
  4 => array(1,2)
);
```

$children example output:

```
array(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2);
```

I'm assuming the children's id are already unique in the database (not 1,2,1,2)

Comment: The new query gets
1 2
2 3
its not getting the left and right child, it get one only
my query got the result as
1 2,3
2 4,5
etc..

can't we just save the result to a new array to keep every thing as it is?

Comment: when you explode the children, explode them into a new array $children, there souldn't be any duplicate if this is a tree, just sort them there. So after your line of code that stores them into $parents, also create oen that stores them into a new $children array.  after you leave the while loop, sort the child array how you want.

Comment: the query result is getting only one child , the left and its not getting the right one.
--
the query i have now get all the parents and childs in the database then the function get a child for the specified parent i send to the function

Comment: so what i need is just get the function result into a new_array.

Comment: yes, use your old code, and inside the while loop, after you insert into th $parents array, also insert into a 2nd array (call it $chlildren), do teh same thing, $children = array_merge($children, explode(',', $row['children'])).  Make sure $children array is defined outside of the while loop